# Is it within the Stack Overflow policy to ask for details on another user's question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I am not sure this is the place to ask, but I was wondering about the Stack Overflow policy on asking for details on another user's question answer.

I sometimes find a question which I was about to ask, but the person asking it has a better programming knowledge than I do, and the answers tend to assume things I don't necessarily know/understand. Is it okay to ask for clarifications in a comment on that answer or should I ask a very similar question, referring to the original question and asking specifically for the point I don't get to be explained in more details?

Comment: Well, I don't know for sure, but I *can* tell you that this is a good question.

Comment: It's ok, to a point. SO is not intended to be a one-on-one helpdesk.

Comment: If you do need an extended discussion on a post you can take it to chat.

Comment: Keep in mind that no matter what you do, someone will probably complain that you should have done it differently.

Comment: @barbecue your comment should have be worded differently... on another question, not this one.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Is it okay to ask for clarifications in a comment on that answer

I mean you can *ask*.  Nobody is obligated to respond at all.  So long as you're respectful and are perfectly okay not getting any kind of response at all, this isn't an *inappropriate* comment to make.

> should I ask a very similar question

You *can*.  Like with any question, you'll want to make sure you're really doing your homework; you not only want to read through all the info in that question deeply to make sure that you can't figure out what you're looking for there, but also that you're researching the topic elsewhere for the information you need.  If the question assumes that you know what some language keyword is and doesn't explain it, then *look up that language keyword* and see what's in the language docs, tutorials, other articles around the web on that topic, etc.

If, after doing your homework, you really can't figure out some aspect of another answer, then yes, you can ask a new question in which you refer to that post (making sure to specifically quote in the question the relevant section(s)) asking for a particular explanation about a particular aspect of an answer (or perhaps describing how that answer fails to apply to your situation).

Comment: `in which you refer to that post...` this should be emphasized: the chances you get wrongly dupe-hammered drop significantly if you can explain why that does not meet your needs or specifically what part of it requires further explanation.

Answer (score 7):

One addendum to Servy's answer:

If you've done all the research and written your good follow-up question as suggested by Servy, it would actually be a good idea to post a comment on the answer, mentioning the new question, like: "@answerer, I posted a new question related to your answer [here](link).  I'd be honored if you could provide any feedback." You're still not guaranteed that the previous answerer will answer, but they will likely appreciate the notification; it's possible they may not have noticed your new question.

I know I've had some people do that on some of my answers.  In that case, I at least take the time to look at the new question.

Comment: I'd not want to encourage this. I've had people who think just because I've answered one of their questions, they can come and ask me about their next question with such a comment (OK, so none of them said they'd be honoured). I'm sure John Skeet doesn't want 30,000 items in his inbox even if they do mention "honoured".

Comment: @BillWoodger Jon himself [has written](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/08/22/stack-overflow-and-personal-emails/) something related in the past - ok it's about emails, but I think the same principles apply here.

Comment: I'd probably reword the comment to something like *"@answerer Thanks for this answer, I posted a new question related to it [here](link). Thought you might appreciate the opportunity to provide feedback"*. That way, you're not asking for anything, just giving a chance if the user wanted to get involved.

Answer (score 5):

For certain cases, I do this with some regularity. When I find an answer that says something like

> Under *foo* configuration, *bar* always does *unintuitive baz.*

and nothing else, I often comment to ask for citations. (Other times, I link the sources myself.)

I believe the answer to your question is that all of those possible actions are appropriate sometimes, and may not be other times. Also, different answerers will react to your actions in different ways. Both [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345793/241211) and [Scott](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345816/241211) have good advice at how to solicit generally positive reactions.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it okay to ask for clarifications in a comment on that answer

Yes! This is what comments are for. :)

Once the clarification has been obtained, the OP should see this as a chance to improve the answer itself, by editing the new details into the narrative of the post. Your comments can then be removed as obsolete, if you like.

However:

> Should I ask a very similar question, referring to the original question and asking specifically for the point I don't get to be explained in more details?

Here you seem to be expecting a little more than just a clarification. You're almost suggesting a related but tangential, separate question. In that case yes ask it separately as you describe.